# How to display images in Froala Editor after ajax respond with a good link in Codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, froala

I'm using **Codeigniter3** and **Froala Editor** for posting some content in my website 
and i'm also create an image upload when click on insert images in **Froala Editor** and after respond from Ajax as a link of images but it don't show in **Froala Editor**

**Issue** Images don't show in **Froala editor** But it has already upload to server(localhost).

Here is my Froala editor

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#edit').editable({
            inlineMode: false,
            mediaManager: false,
            showInsertImage:true,
            imageUploadParam: 'up_img',
            setHTML:true,
            imageUploadURL: 'http://localhost/site/gotoadmin/image/edit_img',
              imageErrorCallback: function (data) { 
              if (data.errorCode == 1) {
                console.log ('bad link')
              }

              else if (data.errorCode == 2) {
                console.log ('bad response')
              }

              else if (data.errorCode == 3) {
                console.log ('upload error')
              }
          }
        })
    });
</script>
```

And This is a function in images controller using CI3 to upload images

```
public function edit_img() {

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $config['upload_path'] = '../assets/img/editor';
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
    $config['max_width'] = '102400';
    $config['max_height'] = '768000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $token = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();

    $res = FALSE;
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('up_img')) {
        $response = FALSE;
    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $response = 'http://localhost/site/assets/img/editor/'.$data['file_name'];
    }
    echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
}
```

Here is my respond data

```
"http://localhost/site/assets/img/editor/back.jpg" (This link is work when I copy past to browser I can see the images)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response should be a JSON. You response should be created differently:

```
$response = new StdClass;
$response->link = 'http://localhost/site/assets/img/editor/'.$data['file_name'];
echo stripslashes(json_encode($response));
```

There are more details about that on the [Froala Editor Php Image Upload](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/server-integrations/php-image-upload) article.